# Proper way to time a WCF Service Call

Tags: .net, vb.net, wcf

I am making synchronous and asynchronous calls to a WCF service from my application. We want to do some custom logging to a database if the call takes longer than a predetermined time. What is the best way to do this? For asynchronous calls I had planned on starting a stopwatch right before the call and stop it when I get the callback. My question is, I suppose, if I use this same method for a synchronous call will this work? Will the stopwatch continue to run while the application is waiting on a response from the WCF service or do I need to run the stopwatch on a different thread? Or is there a better way entirely to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it will work, you don't have to start another thread.

Stopwatch don't care if the thread is waiting for a call to be answered.